# how to activate a function when a value from a drop down list is selected in python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a GUI and I prepared a drop down list.
when the user select one of the drop down list options I want to activate a function.
this is the function I want to call when one of the items in the list is selected:

```
def autoselect():
    autoruntype = str(ui.autorunselect.currentText())
    return
```

I know I should connect them by something like (it's an example of a button):

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.autorunselect, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),autoselect )
```

what should be instead of "clicked" when using drop down list

Comment: use `activated`, `currentTextChanged` or `currentIndexChange, see the docs

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, I still didn't solve one issue - upon user selecting one of the options from the drop down list I want my function to be called (similar to button push), how can I do it? that's why I used the connect option: (but it's not working - it doesn't call my function): :QtCore.QObject.connect(self.autorunselect, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated()")),autoselect)

Comment: edit your question and provide a [mcve], so I'll tell you where the problem is, read [ask]

Comment: solved !! the way I used it is: self.autorunselect.activated[str].connect(autoselect)